# Python, web scraping and BeautifulSoup but does not work

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I wanna to scrape from the following html code a list of all products and if they are "instock" or "outofstock".

```
<div class="js-product-sizer sizes__layout built" data-scope="conversion-zone">   
            <div class="sizes__wrapper sizes__wrapper--visible" data-id="1042303" data-sellableonline="true">
              <span class="sizes__button sizes__button--selected" role="button" data-quantity="">Taglia</span>
              <ul class="sizes__list" role="listbox">
                  <li class="sizes__size" data-id="969834" data-belowthreshold="false" data-quantity="true" data-available-quantity="1631" data-backinstockqualified="false" data-locale="it" data-storeprice="€1,49" data-storename="Cavallino, Lecce" data-price="1.49" data-weight="0.528" data-favstore-stock="10" data-favstore-above-threshold="false" data-favstore-cnc1h="true" aria-labelledby="size-selector-title" role="option">
                    <span class="sizes__info" data-tnr-size-selector-bootstrap-by-text="">0,5 KG</span>
                    <span class="sizes__stock"                                                             
                                  <span class="sizes__stock__info" data-tnr-size-selector-stock-info="">Disponibile</span>                        
                    </span>
                  </li>
                
                  <li class="sizes__size" data-id="969842" data-belowthreshold="false" data-quantity="false" data-available-quantity="0" data-backinstockqualified="true" data-locale="it" data-storeprice="€3,49" data-storename="Cavallino, Lecce" data-price="3.49" data-weight="1.074" data-displayname="Disco ghisa bodybuilding 28mm" data-favstore-stock="0" data-favstore-above-threshold="false" data-favstore-cnc1h="false" aria-labelledby="size-selector-title" role="option">
                    <span class="sizes__info" data-tnr-size-selector-bootstrap-by-text="">1 KG</span>
                    <span class="sizes__stock">   
                              <span class="sizes__stock__info sizes__stock__info--nostock" data-tnr-size-selector-stock-info="">0 disponibili</span>
```

I have run the following code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import time

r = requests.get('https://www.decathlon.it/p/disco-ghisa-bodybuilding-28mm/_/R-p-7278?mc=1042303&c=NERO')
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')

for anchor_tag in soup.find_all(class_="js-product-sizer sizes__layout built")[0].findChildren():
    if "sizes_stock" in anchor_tag['class']:
        print(f"Size {anchor_tag.text} OOS")
    else:
        print(f"Size {anchor_tag.text}  in stock!")
```

But it gives me the following error:

`IndexError: list index out of range`

Comment: From where you copied this HTML code? From your browser or from requests? Note that you can't get the dynamically created content by JavaScript using this way. If it is a JavaScript dynamically created content, then you should use Selenium.

Comment: You could give me an example with selenium code?

Comment: I didn't used Selenium. I used BeautifulSoup on my projects.
And try this before considering about selenium:
Change the for anchor_tag in soup.find_all(...) part like this:
`soup.find_all("div",{"class"="js-product-sizer sizes__layout built"})`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated, they have a way of detecting an automating process to pull info. If you access the page a with selenium, it does bring up the html. So you can use selenium to get the page source, then can parse it.

Also cleaned up your logic a bit there. You were printing `'in stock'` regardless if it was or was not any quantity available.

Also, if you're just going to pull the first element (`soup.find_all(class_="js-product-sizer sizes__layout built")[0]`) when you use `find_all()`, might as well just simply use `find()`, as that's precisely what it returns, the first element it finds.

**Code:**

```
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import time

url = 'https://www.decathlon.it/p/disco-ghisa-bodybuilding-28mm/_/R-p-7278?mc=1042303&c=NERO'


while True:

    driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r'C:/chromedriver_win32/chromedriver.exe')

    meta = 'ROBOTS'
    while meta == 'ROBOTS':
        driver.get(url)
        page = driver.page_source 
        soup = BeautifulSoup(page,'html.parser')
        if 'name' in soup.find('meta').attrs:
            meta = soup.find('meta')['name']
        else:
            meta = False
        
    driver.close()

    anchor_tag = soup.find(class_="js-product-sizer sizes__layout built")
    items_list = anchor_tag.find_all('li')
    for item in items_list:
        if item['data-weight'] == '0.528':
            continue
        quantity = item['data-available-quantity']
        itemStr = item.text.split('\n')
        if int(quantity) > 0:
            itemStr.insert(2,quantity)
        itemStr = ' '.join(itemStr).strip()
        if item['data-available-quantity'] == '0':
            print(f"Size {itemStr} OOS")
        else:
            print(f"Size {itemStr}  in stock!")
    
    time.sleep(60)
```

**Output:**

```
Size 0,5 KG 1584  Disponibile  in stock!
Size 1 KG  0 disponibili OOS
Size 2 KG  0 disponibili OOS
Size 5 KG  0 disponibili OOS
Size 10 KG  0 disponibili OOS
Size 20 KG  0 disponibili OOS
```

Comment: ohhh thanks u. It works. Just a question: if I wanna to repet the code every minutis? How could add a while true: time.sleep(1)

Comment: I have created a function and add while True:
    func()
    time.sleep(1) but every time open a new promt window, I could solve it?

Comment: well you'd want time.sleep(60) (for 60 seconds). But ya, you could create a function, or simply add the 2 lines of code in there ike I did above

Comment: Okey but for every while loops the program open a promt windows, I could cloed it at the end of each while loops?

Comment: sure. or just leave it open. up to you really. But if you leave it open, move the `driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r'C:/chromedriver_win32/chromedriver.exe')`  to before the `while True`,

Comment: Okey it works. And if I wanna to exclude the first records (0.5kg?)

Answer (score -1):

You can see what's wrong with your code by calling

```
r.raise_for_status()
```

or checking `r.status_code` manually.

You'll see `requests.exceptions.HTTPError: 403 Client Error: Forbidden for url:...`. So there's really no div with that class in your response text, and getting element with index 0 is impossible and raises `IndexError`. The website you're trying to scrape is detecting simple scraping requests, try at least setting some headers (maybe [fake_useragent](https://pypi.org/project/fake-useragent/) can help you).

Comment: Don't need a library for user agent.
requests.get(url, headers={"User-Agent":"Mozilla/5.0"}) is mostly enough.

Comment: @electromeow, not in this case. even the simple useragent will return `<html style="height:100%"><head><meta content="NOINDEX, NOFOLLOW" name="ROBOTS"/>...` So that won't work